# My custom Font-Awesome icon is not showing in IE (but fine in all other browsers) - Why?

Tags: css, fonts, icons

I'm using this Font-Awesome fork: https://github.com/bhjortsberg/Font-Awesome to display the Steemit icon. I see it on Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Brave but not on IE11.

Here is my code:

```
<head><link href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
<li>
  <i class="fa fa-steemit"></i> Steemit
</li>
</body>
```

Comment: Check supported features for each browser and specific version: https://caniuse.com/#search=font. Maybe this fork it's using something not supported on Safari or IE11

Comment: Thanks for that link. The problem is only for that specific icon though.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.